# "Draw a bath" vs "prepare a bath"

Tags: expressions

Is there any difference in meaning between the expressions *draw a bath* and *prepare a bath*?

Comment: I would generally "run a bath", but I guess the idiom may vary in different places.

Comment: @WillHunting: I'm guessing this is in reference to stopping up the plug and filling the bath with water, in preparation for taking a bath. Which is not to prejudice the answer in favor of 'prepare a bath'. Frankly, "I'm going to take a bath" would have the same implicature ('don't anybody use hot water from another tap in the next few minutes').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the use of 'draw a bath' may also have survived more in some regions than others. I recall my Dad using that term before, and have used it myself. (south/east USA roots?)

Personally, both prepare and draw a bath seem to indicate forethought about the process, though that could simply be context.

Answer (score 7):

*Draw a bath* is from the days when water was drawn in the sense that it was pumped or supplied in some way that didn't rely simply on water pressure. Neither it, nor *prepare a bath* is normally used now. We speak instead of *running a bath* if we have to.

Comment: O tempora! O mores! Do your bit against global warming - forget the bath, have a shower.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I read somewhere that a power shower, at least, can use more water and energy than a bath.

Comment: I've just decommissioned *two* power showers. The whole house is on now mains pressure following boiler replacement, and it turns out the pumps are not only unnecessary - they couldn't handle the input pressure anyway. So it doesn't apply to me, but my gut feel is the excess heat energy in a bath would probably vastly outweigh the amount used by a pump, so unless you spent a *long* time in the shower it should use far less energy *and* water. But I will see if I can find out more about that.

Comment: ...here's my take, for what it's worth. I used to sometimes put a plug in the shower; if I had a long-ish power shower it would almost fill the tray. From which I can see my shower used 1/3 - 1/2 as much water as the bath. It was pumped by a 500-watt motor, which over, say, 12 minutes would barely be enough energy to boil a kettle of water (my 3kW kettle takes at least 2 minutes). So the extra pump energy is small compared to the extra heat energy in 2-3 times as much water. My shower was definitely more energy-efficient even before...

Comment: ... **now** it's far *more* efficient, because there's no pump, my new boiler is more efficient, I have no hot tank wasting energy, and the shower pressure is (a bit) lower so I'll use a bit less water anyway (and for electrically-heated showers, even with a full 8-10kW element, you get such a low flow-rate that I'm sure they would *always* be much better than a bath).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There may be a PhD in there somewhere.

Comment: I think years ago UK building regs *required* us to have a cold-tank, and only one mains (kitchen) tap. Maybe so we'd still have water for a while if the supply got knocked out by wartime bombing - I don't know. But I do know I used to rant about us being forced over to the continental system with everything on the mains. After a few weeks with no tanks I think I've decided it's a better (simpler) system. Not least because there are less places to worry about leaks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. Not always is the Continent wrong in their ways... And think that we continentals *STILL* rant about your separate taps for hot and cold water in the bathroom.